# Can I associate an IP address to Android remote services?

Tags: android

Can I associate an IP address to Android remote services? I have two machine. I want to set IP and access each other's remote service. Do you anyone know how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Remote services are for between processes (applications) on a single device. They are not for communication between devices.

Comment: hi,CommonsWare

Thank you for providing this important information